# Bad magic number in super-block / Invalid argument while trying to open /dev/sda12

Tags: linux, hard-drive, partition-recovery, superblock

How can i recover my corrupted  hardisk partition ?

I can tried to recover this partition using GParted but GParted see an error message

> GParted 0.25.0 --enable-libparted-dmraid --enable-online-resize
>
> Libparted 3.2 Check and repair file system (ext4) on /dev/sda12
>
> 00:00:05    ( ERROR )
>
> ```
>    calibrate /dev/sda12  00:00:04    ( SUCCESS )
>
>    path: /dev/sda12 (partition) start: 925020160 end: 952363007 size:
> ```
>
> 27342848 (13.04 GiB) check file system on /dev/sda12 for errors
>   and (if possible) fix them  00:00:01    ( ERROR )
>
> ```
>    e2fsck -f -y -v -C 0 /dev/sda12  00:00:01    ( ERROR )
>
>    ext2fs_open2: Superblock checksum does not match superblock e2fsck:
> ```
>
> Superblock invalid, trying backup blocks...
>
> The superblock could not be read or does not describe a valid
>
> ext2/ext3/ext4 filesystem. If the device is valid and it really
>
> contains an ext2/ext3/ext4 filesystem (and not swap or ufs or
>
> something else), then the superblock is corrupt, and you might try
>
> running e2fsck with an alternate superblock: e2fsck -b 8193
>
> or e2fsck -b 32768
>
> e2fsck 1.43.4 (31-Jan-2017) e2fsck: Superblock checksum does not match
>
> superblock while trying to open /dev/sda12
>
> ========================================

And I tried this commands

> sudo mke2fs -n /dev/sda12 mke2fs 1.43.4 (31-Jan-2017) /dev/sda12

This command return

> contains a ext4 file system Proceed anyway? (y,N) y Creating
>
> filesystem with 3417856 4k blocks and 855120 inodes Filesystem UUID:
>
> 2f228517-1b6f-4520-a934-f27ff670c96e Superblock backups stored on
>
> blocks:   32768, 98304, 163840, 229376, 294912, 819200, 884736,
>
> 1605632, 2654208

And I tried to recover superblock using these commands

> e2fsck -b 32768 /dev/sda12
>
> e2fsck -b 98304 /dev/sda12
>
> e2fsck -b 163840 /dev/sda12
>
> e2fsck -b 229376 /dev/sda12
>
> e2fsck -b 294912 /dev/sda12
>
> e2fsck -b 819200 /dev/sda12
>
> e2fsck -b 884736 /dev/sda12
>
> e2fsck -b 1605632 /dev/sda12
>
> e2fsck -b 2654208 /dev/sda12

In the  above commands some of the e2fsck commands return

> e2fsck 1.43.4 (31-Jan-2017)
>
> e2fsck: Bad magic number in super-block while trying to open
>   /dev/sda12
>
> The superblock could not be read or does not describe a valid
>   ext2/ext3/ext4
>
> filesystem.  If the device is valid and it really contains an
>   ext2/ext3/ext4
>
> filesystem (and not swap or ufs or something else), then the
>   superblock
>
> is corrupt, and you might try running e2fsck with an alternate
>   superblock:
>
> ```
> e2fsck -b 8193 <device>
> ```
>
> or
>
> ```
> e2fsck -b 32768 <device>
> ```
>
> /dev/sda12 contains a ext4 file system

and some some of the e2fsck commands return

> e2fsck 1.43.4 (31-Jan-2017)
>
> e2fsck: Invalid argument while trying to open /dev/sda12
>
> The superblock could not be read or does not describe a valid
>   ext2/ext3/ext4
>
> filesystem.  If the device is valid and it really contains an
>   ext2/ext3/ext4
>
> filesystem (and not swap or ufs or something else), then the
>   superblock
>
> is corrupt, and you might try running e2fsck with an alternate
>   superblock:
>
> ```
> e2fsck -b 8193 <device>
> ```
>
> or
>
> ```
> e2fsck -b 32768 <device>
> ```

these errors. Please help me to fix this error and recover my partition.

This partition contain my important data's.

I can also tried to find partitions

> sudo fdisk -l

But this command return an error for

> > Partition 3 does not start on physical sector boundary.
> >
> > Partition 4 does not start on physical sector boundary.
> >
> > Partition 5 does not start on physical sector boundary.
> >
> > Partition 6 does not start on physical sector boundary.
> >
> > Partition table entries are not in disk order.

Full output of sudo fdisk -l

> Disk /dev/sda: 465.8 GiB, 500107862016 bytes, 976773168 sectors
>
> Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
>
> Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
>
> I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
>
> Disklabel type: dos
>
> Disk identifier: 0x5cef0893
>
> Device     Boot     Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
>
> /dev/sda1            2048   1026047   1024000   500M  7
>   HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
>
> /dev/sda2  *      1026048 210755583 209729536   100G  7
>   HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
>
> /dev/sda3       210756735 420469244 209712510   100G  7
>   HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
>
> /dev/sda4       420469306 976771071 556301766 265.3G  f W95 Ext'd
>   (LBA)
>
> /dev/sda5       420469308 630181754 209712447   100G  b W95 FAT32
>
> /dev/sda6       630181818 766766384 136584567  65.1G  7
>   HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
>
> /dev/sda7       766767104 874188799 107421696  51.2G  7
>   HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
>
> /dev/sda8       874190848 923017215  48826368  23.3G  7
>   HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
>
> /dev/sda9       952365056 972773375  20408320   9.7G 83 Linux
>
> /dev/sda10      972775424 976771071   3995648   1.9G 82 Linux swap /
>   Solaris
>
> /dev/sda11      923019264 925018111   1998848   976M 83 Linux
>
> /dev/sda12      925020160 952363007  27342848    13G 83 Linux
>
> > Partition 3 does not start on physical sector boundary.
> >
> > Partition 4 does not start on physical sector boundary.
> >
> > Partition 5 does not start on physical sector boundary.
> >
> > Partition 6 does not start on physical sector boundary.
> >
> > Partition table entries are not in disk order.

Please help me to fix Partition table error and recover my corrupted  hardisk partition /dev/sda12.